# XAudio2 false Targeting windows version

Tags: c++, sdk, xaudio2, steamworks-api

I'm using XAudio2 to run SteamWorksExample game to see how can i include steam stuffs inside my C++ based game, I'm using Windows 10 but when i run code, I got this error:

"This version of XAudio2 is available only in Windows 8 or later. Use the XAudio2 headers and libraries from the DirectX SDK with applications that target Windows 7 and earlier versions."

i checked source files, its on there:

`#if(_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8) #error "This version of XAudio2 is available only in Windows 8 or later. Use the XAudio2 headers and libraries from the DirectX SDK with applications that target Windows 7 and earlier versions." #endif // (_WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)`

how can i solve that error?

Comment: What "SteamWorksExample" game are you using exactly? Ideally that sample should be updated to avoid using the legacy DirectX SDK at all. Plus for Windows 7 SP1 support, they can use [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your VC++ directories, if they are like that:

Include Directories: $(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include

Include Library Directories: $(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86

delete them.

in my case, it solved problem